# OpenCV 3.4 build with CUDA 9.1 on Windows - traincascade not use GPU

Tags: opencv

I builded OpenCV 3.4 with CUDA, Intel TBB, Intel MKL in VS 2015 like [this](https://jamesbowley.co.uk/buildcompile-opencv-v3-3-on-windows-with-cuda-8-0-and-intel-mkltbb/)

When I run traincascade for classifier training, 100% of CPU is used, but the GPU is not used 0%.

Does the OpenCV-traincascade use the functions of the library CUDA for calculations on the GPU?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**

https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/951477/jetson-tk1/are-tools-like-opencv_traincascade-gpu-accelerated-in-opencv4tegra-/

> To train cascade is meant to be used as an offline tool to create a cascade detector, you should try using a powerful desktop system for training, and then use OpenCV4Tegra on Jetson to run the trained classifier on the device.
>
> There is a CUDA accelerated version of the cascade training tool available in the Ubuntu Desktop x64 version of the OpenCV4Tegra package, which can be downloaded here:
> http://developer.nvidia.com/embedded/dlc/l4t-24-1-opencv4tegra-ubuntu

Which sums it up more eloquantly than I could.

Also No - answered [here](http://answers.opencv.org/question/179831/how-opencv_traincascade-can-using-gpu/)

**In Summary**

The `opencv_traincascade` functionality is not developed using GPU code, for reasons I do not know. This tool however is meant to be run offline, and then the results from this training used in your actual detection run-time code which can be GPU optimised.